# unclosed character literal error with radical character

Tags: java, android, android-studio, enums

I have the following class

```
public enum TokenTest {
    T_SQRT("sqrt", '√'),
    T_NUMBER("example", 'a');

    private Character symbol;
    private String function;

    TokenTest() {}

    TokenTest(Character symbol) {
        this(null, symbol);
    }

    TokenTest(String function) {
        this(function, null);
    }

    TokenTest(String function, Character symbol) {
        this.function = function;
        this.symbol = symbol;
    }
}
```

I am getting this error as shown in image below :

[image]

The problem is with the radical `'√'` in `T_SQRT("sqrt",'√')`
If I replace with anything else, the code compiles normally without any error.

Answer (score 1):

Try using the unicode value (see [Unicode Character 'SQUARE ROOT' (U+221A)](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/221a/index.htm))

```
T_SQRT("sqrt",'\u221A')
```

Comment: i know it can work this way but i need it to be √ instead .it use to work before

Comment: I can't seem to be able to reproduce it. When you say it worked before, before what? What changed?

Comment: @has19 One thing comes to mind, are your single quotes proper single quotes? could be a copy paste error and you have a tick or some other character which looks like a single quote. Can you make sure that you type the single quotes and not copy paste them.